# postgreSQL : cómo usar el VALOR de una consulta como nombre de campo de otra consulta?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla en la que registro cambios

### CAMBIOS

| idcambio | tabla | campo | valoranterior | valoractual | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | chofer | nombre | carlos | luis | 2022-08-01 |
| 2 | autos | marca | ferrari | renault | 2021-01-01 |

y hago la consulta

```
select campo 
    from CAMBIOS 
where idcambio = 1
```

y me devuelve **nombre**

Quiero usar ese valor, como campo en otra consulta, por ejemplo:

```
select id, nombre, masCampos from otraTabla
```

Probé esto, pero no funciona

```
 select id
      , (select campo from CAMBIOS where idcambio = 1)
      , masCampos 
    from otraTabla
```

Alguna idea, sugerencia, salvación épica, documentación para leer? Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Puedes usar código dinámico. [Dynamic code in postgreSql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-dynamic.html)

Comment: Debería funcionar lo que haces, si a la subquery le metes un: 'AS nombre' para poder  referenciarlo en el resto de la query.

Comment: No me funciona, porque en lugar de traerme el valor de "nombre" de otraTabla, me pone el valor "nombre". 
@Javifer2 Estoy mirando lo de Dynamic PG, tal vez sea por ahí la solución. O escribir una función. Me temo que dentro de la función me tope con el mismo problema. Gracias!

Comment: No me funcionó, es algo dificil de detectar. Probablemente, sea porque no lo has hecho como debe de ser....pero como no has puesto el código. Tienes que hacer un código dinámico, donde la parte que es una ` (select campo from CAMBIOS where idcambio = 1)` eso esta fuera del varchar que va a ejecutar el query dinámico. Este enlace es de TSQL, pero es casi igual. Fíjate como se hace. [codigo dinámico](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/02/03/sql-dinamico-como-se-hace/). Fíjate en el code 1.6. Es similar, una parte que va en una cadena y una parte antes de la cadena....

Comment: Realmente el código dinámico, en tú caso, prepara una cadena con `Select ....., ` luego le adiciona el resultado de una query a la cadena. Luego le vuelve a adicionar la parte correspondiente de la cadena `, columna, columna from laTabla;` Y así resuelve porque se ejecuta antes la parte que resuelve el nombre de la columna introduciendo lo que corresponde en la cadena, y luego se ejecuta el código de la cadena. Siempre hay que tener en cuenta la inyección SQL. SUPERIMPORTANTE

Answer (score -1):

Agrega TOP 1 para asegurarte que solo devuelva 1

```
--Para SQL Server
 select  id
      , (select TOP 1 campo from CAMBIOS where idcambio = 1) as nombreCampo
      , masCampos 
    from otraTabla

--Para MySQL

select  id
      , (select campo from CAMBIOS where idcambio = 1 LIMIT 1) as nombreCampo
      , masCampos 
    from otraTabla
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se realizaría lo que se pregunta en postgresql? Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [answer].

Comment: y que es TOP 1 ... esto es una respuesta a medias ...

Comment: la pregunta es sobre postgress..... y no, esto no funciona...